# CSS Responsive Dropdown Menu - Split into 2 Columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I've looked through all the support here and have tried many different ways to split this CSS Dropdown menu into 2 columns, as I have many entries that stretch the nav list down below the fold.

Even though the menu is responsive, I just need the two columns to work when its expanded, not when it shrinks for mobile browsing (that aspect is fine). I'm using jQuery script as well.

I have not yet been successful using any adjustments to my code. Anyone have advice on how I can split this drop-down into 2 side-by-side columns?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu' class='align-center'>
<ul>
 <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
 <li class='has-sub'><a href='equipment.html'>Equipment</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href='#'>Automotive</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Building Equip.</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Concrete Tools</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Drills</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Generators</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Heaters</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Household Equip.</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Ladders</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Painting</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Party / Canopy</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Plumbing</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Pumps</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Sanders</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Saws</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Stage</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Table & Chairs</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Trailers</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Trenchers</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Garden & Lawn Care</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Miscellaneous</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href='concrete.html'>Concrete</a></li>
 <li><a href='gravel.html'>Gravel</a></li>
 <li><a href='propane.html'>Propane</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #468cc6;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5d9bcd 0%, #3677ae 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #5d9bcd), color-stop(100%, #3677ae));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5d9bcd 0%, #3677ae 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5d9bcd 0%, #3677ae 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5d9bcd 0%, #3677ae 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5d9bcd 0%, #3677ae 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url('images/bg.png');
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 18px 25px 21px 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.12);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #3c85c1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 45px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #c7def0;
  right: 17px;
  top: 22.5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #468cc6;
  top: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #468cc6;
  top: 11px;
  left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul::after {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #468cc6;
  left: auto;
  right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  top: 120px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}    
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  width: 180px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #468cc6;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  right: 17px;
  top: 14px;
  top: 14.5px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  right: auto;
  left: 17px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-left-color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-right-color: #333333;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}



@media all and (max-width: 725px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {



  #cssmenu {
    background: #468cc6;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
   padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    border-right: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 18px 25px 18px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: url('images/bg.png');
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #c7def0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c7def0;
    right: 25px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #c7def0;
    right: 25px;
    top: 28px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
  $('#cssmenu #menu-button').on('click', function(){
    var menu = $(this).next('ul');
    if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
      menu.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      menu.addClass('open');
    }
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you tried `column-count`? Also, divs cannot be a child of a `ul` only `li` are allowed.

Comment: @Paulie_D -- I did try adding `column-count: 2;` inside of `#cssmenu ul ul {` but it still didn't work. 

(Just removed the DIV from the dropdown HTML, was from a failed test and forgot to remove the code before posting. Thanks for catching it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but I got this working in two columns for screen sizes above 480px wide.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > div {
        width: 200%;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > div > li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Days of trial and error and you fixed it with a few lines. Works perfectly for what I need. Elegant or not, it got the job done! Cant thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the HTML:

```js
$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    $('.has-ancho > a').on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent('.has-ancho').toggleClass('open').find('i:eq(0)').toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');
      if (!$(this).parent('.has-ancho').hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).parent('.has-ancho').find('.has-ancho').removeClass('open');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.sub-menu').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-arrow,
.menu-heading {
  display: none;
}
.sub-menu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.ancho {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .ancho {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .menu-arrow,
  .menu-heading {
    display: block;
  }
  .ancho a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    margin: 3px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .ancho a i {
    float: right;
  }
  .ancho a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C3C3;
  }
  .ancho .has-ancho > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .ancho .has-ancho.open > .sub-menu {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .ancho .has-ancho.open > a {
    background-color: #B7B7B7;
    color: #FFF;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <ul class="ancho">
        <li class="has-ancho">
          <a href="#" class="menu-heading">menu <i class="fa fa-angle-down menu-arrow"></i></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home 6</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```