# How to split this menu into two columns?

Tags: html, css

I have following code for this image. But i want to split the product menu into two colums.

```
[vc_row enbale_extend_design_options="yes" vc_custom_design_options_reponsive="%5B%7B%22screen%22%3A%22custom%22%2C%22screen_custom%22%3A%221024%22%2C%22background_image_none%22%3A%22yes%22%7D%5D" css=".vc_custom_1548125627238{padding-top: 25px !important;padding-right: 30px !important;padding-bottom: 150px !important;padding-left: 30px !important;background-image: url(https://tangofabrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bgmenu.jpg?id=3081) !important;background-position: 0 0 !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;border-radius: 3px !important;}" responsive_js_composer_custom_id="responsive_js_composer_custom_css_1848579383" el_class="bg-shop"][vc_column offset="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-md-4" responsive_js_composer_custom_id="responsive_js_composer_custom_css_843216826"][lebe_custommenu style="style-01" title="Discover" menu="discover" custommenu_custom_id="lebe_custom_css_382494862" responsive_js_composer_custom_id="responsive_js_composer_custom_css_1825951247" css=".vc_custom_1548316865456{padding-bottom: 20px !important;}"][/vc_column][vc_column offset="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-md-4" responsive_js_composer_custom_id="responsive_js_composer_custom_css_1343847516"][lebe_custommenu style="style-01" title="Products" menu="products" custommenu_custom_id="lebe_custom_css_59645647" responsive_js_composer_custom_id="responsive_js_composer_custom_css_16630816" css=".vc_custom_1547603029191{padding-bottom: 20px !important;}][/vc_column][vc_column offset="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-md-4" responsive_js_composer_custom_id="responsive_js_composer_custom_css_1472824855"][lebe_custommenu style="style-01" title="Whole Sale" menu="whole-sale" custommenu_custom_id="lebe_custom_css_1688727375" responsive_js_composer_custom_id="responsive_js_composer_custom_css_666722841" css=".vc_custom_1547603037530{padding-bottom: 20px !important;}"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Give a fix height to product container and use {display: flex and flex-wrap:wrap}

Comment: Hi thank you for your guidance. Can you plz check the code i posted in the  description and fix the issue i am having with it? I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Muhammad, that is not a working code, if you want me to fix your code then please provide the snippet in simple HTML.

Comment: I think this answer you. [CSS Responsive Dropdown Menu - Split into 2 Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348061/css-responsive-dropdown-menu-split-into-2-columns/35313651)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Css property **'column-count'** on the parent:

```
    column-count: 2;
```